# Why does this produce a nameError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

Running this code produces a nameError saying `ret` is not defined.  Why does the `ret` work in the `if action == 'state'` block but not in the `elif action == list` block?

```
if action == 'stat':
   ret = pp.stat()
   print ret
   sys.exit()
elif action == 'list':
  for i in range(1, ret[0]+1):
      mlist = pp.top(i, 0)
      print 'line: ', len(mlist[1])
  ret = pp.list()
  print ret
```

Comment: Please post code that does what you describe; the examples posted currently are incomplete. That doesn't mean post more code, it means edit the code until it does what you say it does. To demonstrate behaviour, construct a [Short, Self-Contained, Complete Example](http://sscce.org/) including the traceback if any.

Answer (score 0):

`if action == 'stat'` is false then `ret` never gets defined

so when the elif is executed then ret is never defined

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing `ret` before the variable is instanciated in the for loop. Move `ret = pp.list()` up before the for loop, and you'll be ok.

```
elif action == 'list':
  ret = pp.list()
  for i in range(1, ret[0]+1):
      mlist = pp.top(i, 0)
      print 'line: ', len(mlist[1])
  print ret
```